# Вытащить (распарсить из файла нужные данные

Tags: парсер

Есть .txt файл, в него записывается некая информация, необходимо из него достать определенную информацию.
Вот пример строчки, что записывается в этот файл.

> [Success] Платеж. Параметры: Служба :0, ИД водителя:06325, ИД терминала:3, Сумма:400, Дата плажежа:20211026225636
> [Success] Платеж. Параметры: Служба :0, ИД водителя:06521, ИД терминала:3, Сумма:150, Дата плажежа:20211027002503

Мне необходимо вытягивать сумму и дату приводить в более красивый вид, например хотя бы к такому виду: 2021-10-27.00:25:03

Сумму выводить без всяких букв лишних, просто числа, ну или же выводить к пример так:

Дата: 2021-10-27.00:25:03
450
444
111
222
223
...

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ну так приступайте, раз нужно) а то не видно, что вы уже сделали или попробовали